# For Next loop in MS-Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, append, attachment, ms-access-2013

I asked for help on accessforums and was given code:

```
Public Sub InsertData()
Dim dbs As dao.Database, rst As Recordset, rstInsert As Recordset
Dim sSQL As String
Dim sSQLSource As String
Dim i

Set dbs = CurrentDb

sSQLSource = "SELECT Route, Account, [Date], "
sSQLSource = sSQLSource & "[Door 1].FileData, [Door 1].FileName, [Door 1].FileType, "
sSQLSource = sSQLSource & "[Door 2].FileData, [Door 2].FileName, [Door 2].FileType, "
sSQLSource = sSQLSource & "[Door 3].FileData, [Door 3].FileName, [Door 3].FileType, "
sSQLSource = sSQLSource & "[Door 4].FileData, [Door 4].FileName, [Door 4].FileType, "
sSQLSource = sSQLSource & "[Door 5].FileData, [Door 5].FileName, [Door 5].FileType, "
sSQLSource = sSQLSource & "[Door 6].FileData, [Door 6].FileName, [Door 6].FileType, "
sSQLSource = sSQLSource & "[Door 7].FileData, [Door 7].FileName, [Door 7].FileType, "
sSQLSource = sSQLSource & "[Door 8].FileData, [Door 8].FileName, [Door 8].FileType, "
sSQLSource = sSQLSource & "[Door 9].FileData, [Door 9].FileName, [Door 9].FileType, "
sSQLSource = sSQLSource & "[Door 10].FileData, [Door 10].FileName, [Door 10].FileType, "
sSQLSource = sSQLSource & "[Door 11].FileData, [Door 11].FileName, [Door 11].FileType, "
sSQLSource = sSQLSource & "[Door 12].FileData, [Door 12].FileName, [Door 12].FileType, "
sSQLSource = sSQLSource & "[Door 13].FileData, [Door 13].FileName, [Door 13].FileType, "
sSQLSource = sSQLSource & "[Door 14].FileData, [Door 14].FileName, [Door 14].FileType, "
sSQLSource = sSQLSource & "[Door 15].FileData, [Door 15].FileName, [Door 15].FileType, "
sSQLSource = sSQLSource & "Comments "
sSQLSource = sSQLSource & "FROM Submit"

Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(sSQLSource)

If rst.RecordCount <> 0 Then
    Do While rst.EOF <> True
        Debug.Print rst!route
        If DCount("*", "imgdest", "[Route] = " & rst!route) = 0 Then
            Debug.Print "    NO EXISTING RECORD"
            Debug.Print "    " & rst![door 1.filename]
            If Not IsNull(rst![door 1.filename]) Then
                Debug.Print "    Image in 1"
                Set rstInsert = dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT Route, Account, [Date], [Door 1].FileData, [Door 1].FileName, [Door 1].FileType, Comments FROM imgDest")
                rstInsert.AddNew
                rstInsert![route] = rst![route]
                rstInsert![account] = rst![account]
                rstInsert![Date] = rst![Date]
                rstInsert![Door 1.Filedata] = rst![Door 1.Filedata]
                rstInsert![door 1.filename] = rst![door 1.filename]
                rstInsert![comments] = rst![comments]
                rstInsert.Update
                rstInsert.Close
            End If
            'REPEAT THE CODE BELOW FOR EACH OF YOUR POSSIBLE IMAGE FIELDS
            If Not IsNull(rst![door 2.filename]) Then
                Debug.Print "    Image in 2"
                Set rstInsert = dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT Route, [Door 2].FileData, [Door 2].FileName, [Door 2].FileType FROM imgDest WHERE [route] = " & rst!route)
                rstInsert.Edit
                rstInsert![Door 2.Filedata] = rst![Door 2.Filedata]
                rstInsert![door 2.filename] = rst![door 2.filename]
                rstInsert.Update
                rstInsert.Close
            End If
            If Not IsNull(rst![door 3.filename]) Then
                Debug.Print "    Image in 3"
                Set rstInsert = dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT Route, [Door 3].FileData, [Door 3].FileName, [Door 3].FileType FROM imgDest WHERE [route] = " & rst!route)
                rstInsert.Edit
                rstInsert![Door 3.Filedata] = rst![Door 3.Filedata]
                rstInsert![door 3.filename] = rst![door 3.filename]
                rstInsert.Update
                rstInsert.Close
            End If

            Next i
        End If
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop
Else
    MsgBox "NO records to process"
End If
rst.Close
Set dbs = Nothing
End Sub
```

However, each time I attempt to run this code I'm given the error "Next without For". As I understand it, the Next i line will run the next "door" append. However, I'm new to VB and I'm unsure what "For" command to use and where to enter it. I'd greatly appreciate some help in this matter.

Comment: @simoco If I remove Next i the doors that follow Door 2 do not get appended.

Comment: In addition to the fine suggestions above, whoever gave you this code is a menace, if a well-meaning one. From the looks of it, you can do this task using Insert & Select queries - faster & easier to see what's being done.

Comment: The issue was I have to append attachments, which are multivalued fields and using append queries is not possible with multivalued fields. The old code I had is in a previous question of mine here on StackOverflow, it did not work if there was more than one picture to be appended. @Tim

Answer (score 0):

You can and really should DRY this out a bit. It will help your code and your debugging greatly. I try not to provide code examples that I would be unable to test fully and without access to your DB I obviously cannot do this but here is a concept for you to expand on

```
Dim numberOfDoors As Integer
Dim sSQLSource AS String

numberOfDoors = 15

sSQLSource = "SELECT Route, Account, [Date], "

For i = 1 To numberOfDoors
    sSQLSource = sSQLSource & buildSelect(i)
Next i

sSQLSource = sSQLSource & "Comments "
sSQLSource = sSQLSource & "FROM Submit"

Function buildSelect(doorNumber As Integer) As String
    Dim door AS String
    door = "Door " & doorNumber
    buildSelect = "[" & door & "].FileDate, [" & door & "].FileName, [" & door & "].FileType, "
End Function
```

Your SQL statement will come out looking the same and the code will be far more readable.

A Similar concept can be applied to your update Queries.

AS @simoco stated the `Next i` is causing the issue for you currently and `i` is not even being used in the code provided. I think that a loop for your update queries is the right direction just modularize the code a bit so you and future yous can read and understand what is happening